# IOS Push notifications works locally but not on bluehost

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, shared-hosting, apns-php

I used the php script below to send push notifications and it's working perfect if sent from my local computer using "wamp server"

I am using now bluehost services and bought a dedicated ip and they opened apns ports for me 2195 and 2196

but i am always receiving "APNS Connection Failed : 0" while the same code is working perfect locally

any help guys ? and thanks in advance.

> stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in
> /public_html/simplepush.php
>
> stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in
> /public_html/simplepush.php

Code :

```
    <?php




//$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$tHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$tPort = 2195;
// Provide the Certificate and Key Data.
    
$tCert = 'Key.pem';
$tPassphrase = 'mypasssss';
$tToken = "5d0897edddb84f38b951109dce8b99b7a7c7446d57b78a154f057d47dd878ac2";

$tAlert = 'New news has been added';
$tBadge = 1;
$tSound = 'default';
$tPayload = 'xxx';

$tBody['aps'] = array (
'alert' => $tAlert,
'badge' => $tBadge,
'sound' => $tSound,
);

$tBody ['payload'] = $tPayload;
$tBody = json_encode ($tBody);

$tContext = stream_context_create ();
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $tCert);
stream_context_set_option ($tContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $tPassphrase);

// Open the Connection to the APNS Server.
$tSocket = stream_socket_client ('ssl://'.$tHost.':'.$tPort, $error, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $tContext);
// Check if we were able to open a socket.
if (!$tSocket)
exit ("APNS Connection Failed: $error $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

// Build the Binary Notification.
$tMsg = chr (0) . chr (0) . chr (32) . pack ('H*', $tToken) . pack ('n', strlen ($tBody)) . $tBody;

// Send the Notification to the Server.
$tResult = fwrite ($tSocket, $tMsg, strlen ($tMsg));
if ($tResult)
echo 'Delivered Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Could not Deliver Message to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the Connection to the Server.
fclose ($tSocket);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every one facing this problem go and **generate a fresh new .pem file** and everything will work